# Python time formats not matching?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am getting the error:

```
 time data '1/1/03 0:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (match)
```

Does this format not match..? I am new to working with Date-Time formats so this is rather confusing to me.

This is the line of code I am using:

```
date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Note that the csv file, 'df' that is being used has 1 column named "time", hence I am getting all possible values of it with df['time'].

I should comment that this is:

```
12/31/16 23:00
```

is another entry, so I know that it goes month/day/year, is it because the year is only two digits?

Comment: https://strftime.org/ is a pretty good resource for this

Comment: Seriously, fix the data format. Didn't we learn anything from the Y2k debacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the matching of the year. `%Y` matches the year with the century so in that case it should be `2003` to be matched. You should use `%y` instead.

```
date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is the year:

```
date_time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M') # the lowercase y fixes it
```

Its basically the same as in the datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt;

dt.strptime('1/1/03 0:00', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
>> datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 1, 0, 0)

dt.strptime('1/1/03 0:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
>> ## ERROR
```

[All the codes to clarify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)